# HTTP call with Socks 4 proxy

Tags: java, proxy, socks

I need to call a server using a socks 4 proxy. I am on java version 1.6.

If we use something like this then it treats the SOCKS proxy as version 5.

```
 URL url = new URL("https://www.google.com");  
 URLConnection connection = null;  
 SocketAddress proxySocketAddress1 =  new InetSocketAddress("XXXXXXXXXX", 8081);  
 Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxySocketAddress1);  
 connection = url.openConnection(proxy);  
 connection.setConnectTimeout(150000);  
 connection.connect();
```

I can setup socks proxy at the system level by doing

```
// Set SOCKS proxy
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost","xxxxx");
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort","1234");
System.getProperties().put("socksProxyVersion","4");
```

When I do this I am able to reach the server

```
connection = url.openConnection();
```

But my other connections like connections to db, encryption server also goes thru the proxy and fails.

I also tried excluding servers from system proxy but no success.

```
System.getProperties().put("socksnonProxyHosts","*.net");
System.getProperties().put("http.nonProxyHosts","*.net");
```

Is there any other way I can choose to use SOCKS4 in java 1.6.

Comment: `socksnonProxyHosts` isn't listed in [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html), nor anything like it. (Neither is `socksProxyVersion,` but the bug link given by @RemyLebeau describes it as added in Java 7.)

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the `SocksSocketImpl` implementation:

[JDK-6964547 : Impossible to set useV4 in SocksSocketImpl](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964547)

Comment: NB It is listed as fixed in Java 7.

Comment: Is there any way using standard jdk libraries to use SOCKS4 proxy in any JDK? I read the bug, it says - "The proposed, socksProxyVersion, property does not have any impact of SOCKS proxies set programatically through java.net.Proxy". that means I cannot set it on individual socket connections.

Comment: Have you considered writing your own `Proxy`-derived class to implement SOCKS v4 yourself? It is a very simple protocol to implement manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I tried and seems like it's working. Basically I need SOCKS4 proxy to connect to a socket.

```
SocketAddress socketAddress =  new InetSocketAddress("proxyhost",proxyport);
Proxy socketProxy =  new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socketAddress);

Socket  socket = new Socket(socketProxy); 
Class clazzSocks  = socket.getClass();
Method setSockVersion  = null;
Field sockImplField = null; 
SocketImpl socksimpl = null; 
 try {
    sockImplField = clazzSocks.getDeclaredField("impl");
    sockImplField.setAccessible(true);
    socksimpl  = (SocketImpl) sockImplField.get(socket);
    Class clazzSocksImpl  =  socksimpl.getClass();
    setSockVersion  = clazzSocksImpl.getDeclaredMethod("setV4");
    setSockVersion.setAccessible(true);
    if(null != setSockVersion){
        setSockVersion.invoke(socksimpl);
    }
    sockImplField.set(socket, socksimpl);
    } 
        catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    } 

String hostName="xxxxx";
int port=1080;
InetAddress address;        
SocketAddress socketAddress;            
address = InetAddress.getByName(hostName);
socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(address, port);

// Connect to socket
socket.connect(socketAddress, 100000);

//setting the socket read() connection time out 
socket.setSoTimeout(100000);
```

Please share your comments, feedback for this approach.

Comment: Since SocksSocketImpl class is not public so I used reflection to access setV4 method. Techinically it seems correct and working as well. Just wanted some logical feedback of using this.