# Why does my SOCKS proxy code throw SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server?

Tags: java, http, proxy, socks

Why does my SOCKS proxy code throw `SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server`? I've tried to set in URLConnection or other, but this doesn't work. Only thing that worked - chilkat lib, but it's commercial. So, how I, for example, make http request through a ASOCKS proxy? Maybe exist some free lib for that?

For example, that code:

```
    SocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(proxy_ip, proxy_port);
    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, addr);
    Socket socket = new Socket(proxy);
    InetSocketAddress dest = new InetSocketAddress("google.com", 80);
    try {
        socket.connect(dest);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CheckProxy.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Throws exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at proxychecker.CheckProxy.SocksCheck(CheckProxy.java:86)
```

Where line 86 is "socket.connect(dest);"

Comment: There are two ways and they are both documented.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Okay. I've used many ways to solve that. In general, i receive exception:"java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server". Exception isn't depends of implementation, for e.x. i've tryed code from the last comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742103/http-call-with-socks-4-proxy .

Comment: This is now basically a duplicate of [HTTP call with Socks 4 proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742103/http-call-with-socks-4-proxy). See also [this Java bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964547).

Comment: @prophet that is not the case here.

Comment: It took you 7 years to recognize that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explanation of this bug: [bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964547](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964547)

You need to manually change mode in Socket object using this code:

```
Class clazzSocks  = socket.getClass();
Method setSockVersion  = null;
Field sockImplField = null; 
SocketImpl socksimpl = null; 
try {
  sockImplField = clazzSocks.getDeclaredField("impl");
  sockImplField.setAccessible(true);
  socksimpl  = (SocketImpl) sockImplField.get(socket);
  Class clazzSocksImpl  =  socksimpl.getClass();
  setSockVersion  = clazzSocksImpl.getDeclaredMethod("setV4");
  setSockVersion.setAccessible(true);
  if(null != setSockVersion){
      setSockVersion.invoke(socksimpl);
  }
  sockImplField.set(socket, socksimpl);
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
```

That indicates that you don't have a SOCKS proxy at all. Possibly it is an HTTP proxy.

And note that you asked the wrong question. Your code was correct, it was your premiss that was wrong.

Comment: Trying different server, I have determined that it is not working only servers with SOCKS4. SOCKS5 server to function properly. Actually, how to tell java that I'm using the fourth version of the protocol? `System.setProperty("socksProxyVersion", "4");` isn't working. Thanks for help. Example of socks servers may be founded here - http://incloak.com/proxy-list/ .

Comment: And i see description of this fenomen here  - http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964547 . How enable it?

Comment: @PterPterkovich You should post that information as an answer.

Comment: I have the same ISSUE (Java 7 & 8) 
I found SOCKS proxy and it works, and works ONLY when I point it as SOCKS In the IE, winows PC)
ANd when I try to use in in the PROSY connection I receve same Malformed reply from SOCKS server

Comment: @EJP how to check if it's a socks4 or socks5 proxy?

Comment: @user1872384 Ask your netadmin?